# how to Cancel a Recurring payment via Paypal's API and get the instant notification on my site usng IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I want that user can Cancel a Recurring payment via Paypal's API and also Use the PAYpal IPN to get the instant notifcation.
how can i achieve the instant notifications.

I am using following code to cancel recurring payment :-

$cancel_payment = change_subscription_status( $paypal_profileid , 'Cancel' );

```
function change_subscription_status( $profile_id, $action ) {

$api_request = 'USER=' . urlencode( 'api_username' )
            .  '&PWD=' . urlencode( 'api_password' )
            .  '&SIGNATURE=' . urlencode( 'api_signature' )
            .  '&VERSION=76.0'
            .  '&METHOD=ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus'
            .  '&PROFILEID=' . urlencode( $profile_id )
            .  '&ACTION=' . urlencode( $action )
            .  '&NOTE=' . urlencode( 'Profile cancelled at store' );

$ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );

// Uncomment these to turn off server and peer verification
// curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
// curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

// Set the API parameters for this transaction
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $api_request );

// Request response from PayPal
$response = curl_exec( $ch );

// If no response was received from PayPal there is no point parsing the response
if( ! $response )
    die( 'Calling PayPal to change_subscription_status failed: ' . curl_error( $ch ) . '(' . curl_errno( $ch ) . ')' );

curl_close( $ch );

// An associative array is more usable than a parameter string
parse_str( $response, $parsed_response );

return $parsed_response;
 }
```

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly you're asking here, but IPNs occur when you've configuring an IPN URL into your account, and written and installed an IPN handler at that URL.

Comment: can you explain me where i need to define the IPN url in my code. coz while paypal subscripton i have mention it in hidden form.
IN my account i have enabled the IPN url. so the ipn url is called when i use paypal Subscribe.
but in unsubscribe i am not sure how to do that?
i'll really appreciate if you provide me a piece of code to explain

Comment: I didn't say anything about 'defin[ing] the IPN url in [your] code'. I said you have to configure it 'into your account'.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend reviewing the [IPN documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) to get fully familiar with it.

You can define an IPN URL in your API calls most of the time, however, with recurring payments that won't work.  You'll need to make sure it's [configured in your PayPal account profile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/).